Use of generic "one" without having to revel the gender
I want to say the following:

The more one knows about a subject, the more one realizes how little he knows about it.

I want to make it formal and general, thus my use of "one" instead of "a person".
However, at the end of that sentence, I found myself having to use a pronoun ("he" in this case) which feels like it breaks the generalization introduced by "one".
I could make it gender neutral, by changing he/she, but not only this leaves non-binary genders out, also I don't like it either:

The more one knows about a subject, the more one realizes how little he/she knows about it.

Or I can repeat the "one" formula, but them it feels incorrect (I'm talking about that specific person, not a generic one).

The more one knows about a subject, the more one realizes how little one knows about it.

What are my options? How can I write such sentence using "one" (or another formal generic term)?
Would using a generic singular they be a good option here? or is there a better option?

The more one knows about a subject, the more one realizes how little they know about it.


Just replace "he" with "one". There's no rule limiting the number of times "one" can be used in a sentence.

where you wrote he/she, I would just say they. 'The more someone knows about a subject, the more they realize how little they truly know.'

You want 'they', then work backwards to support it: "The more people know about a subject, the more they realize how little they know about it."

I would use the general "you": The more you know about a subject, the more you realizes how little you know about it.. Your use of "he/she" is ambiguous - it sounds as if you are talking about another person.

@Greybeard Why is this question off-topic?

@Mary-Lou: unless I pressed the wrong button, that was not my reason for closing it.

@Greybeard  So what was your reason for closing it?

“Or I can repeat the "one" formula, but the[n] it feels incorrect (I'm talking about that specific person, not a generic one).” — One is generic and refers to ‘anyone’, but it is most often intended to indirectly refer to either the speaker (in this case you) or the addressee (in this case the reader) as a representative of the generic ‘anyone’. Repeating one a third time here would be perfectly natural and refer to the same person as the first two; in fact, if you start out with two one’s like this, it’s almost the only natural option. He and they certainly don’t work.

@JanusBahsJacquet: This is (at least partly) a US/UK difference.  What you’re describing is traditional UK usage, where one works as a fully-fledged pronoun: “The longer one lives, the wiser one becomes.”  In traditional US usage, it works more like someone, introducing a generic individual who thereafter gets an ordinary pronoun: “The longer one lives, the wiser he becomes.”  Since both versions are a little old-fashioned in colloquial use, many people (in writing) follow literary examples more than their own speaker’s intuition, and so end up with a patchy mix of the two systems.

@PLL Huh, I was not actively aware of that AmE usage at all. It’s possible I’ve come across it and just not noticed it in context, but actively thinking about, as I obviously did when reading this question, I instinctively assigned a different referent to he. Though I would guess that even in the US, you would not use one twice and then switch to he only for the last instance? “The longer one lives, the more he realises how little he knows” might work, but the version in the question sounds like a generic someone will eventually realise how little a specific other guy knows.


Would using a generic singular they be a good option here? or is there a better option?

I suggest abandoning the impersonal pronoun "one", and replacing it with "you".

The more you know about something, the more you realize how little you [do] know.

The generic "you" is singular and plural, neutral, appropriate and of course, gender free. You could replace "you" with "we" if you wanted to sound more inclusive, and less direct.
From the web:

The More You Know The More You Realize You Don't Know

Google Books:

“The more we know about the body, the more we realize how little we know.” source

However, there is no rule forbidding using the pronoun one as frequently as needed, it all depends on the audience. I found these examples when the OP expressed the desire to sound formal, and perhaps, more elegant? IMO, the first example overdoes it though.

(a) The more one knows the dizzier one gets. The more one knows about a subject the more one knows how much one does not know and how, quite possibly, and even justly, one could fail.
Trust in an Age of Arrogance By C. Fitzsimons Allison


(b) And as far as experts in the area, you would have difficulty getting experts to claim they're experts; because the more one knows about a subject, the more one recognizes the bounds of one's knowledge.


I don't think "you" captures the essence that "one" gives. Maybe my choice of sentence was not good. I was looking for a solution that keeps the essence of "one" without having to use the pronoun "he" in a more literary/poetic way, that goes beyond individuals. The "one" carries a meaning that is lost when using "you"

@Elerium115 fair enough. Although I understand your hesitancy to embrace "you" and "we", I don't particularly share it. I have found examples online that repeat the same pronoun "one" several times, so if you do choose to keep "one" continue using it, don't swap pronouns in the middle or at the end of an idiomatic phrase.

Also, if you're going to use the word "dizzier" like that, there's no stylistic/register reason to use "one" instead of "you".

An elegant solution. And yes, if OP asks for help, we get to revisit the whole, not just the allowed parts.

Super-technically speaking, the pronoun you is not quite ‘number-neutral’ because as a subject it still always requires a plural verb never a singular one even when it refers to just one person. But its corresponding reflexive and intensive pronoun does display number specificity via yourself for the singular and yourselves for the plural. // It is, however, ‘case-neutral’ between subject and object forms, the same way it is and unlike he/him &c. But it does have a distinct case inflections for your versus yours.

@tchrist isn't "you" used for the second person singular? The meaning is singular if I address an individual , but plural when I am speaking to a group. Nowadays  "you is" and "you was" is becoming increasingly heard and used. M-W tells me “Initially, the distinction between singular you and plural you was signaled by verb agreement; ‘you was’ for the singular continued in polite if informal use well into the 18th century before it lost respectability.”

@Mari-LouA Maybe it's because I'm old, but "you is" and "you was" sound non-standard to me, reminding me of AAVE or hillbilly dialect.

The Brits say it as well.

@Mari-LouA Even in the UK, “you is” and “you was” are used only in certain dialects; TMK, they're very far from being standard.

@Mari-LouA To my knowledge, in most dialects that allow "you is," "is" can be used regardless of whether the referent of "you" is singular or plural. Such dialects also allow "We is" and "They is."

@Barmar  ITV's presenter of This Morning, Eamon Holmes: “I'm thinking about how to get radiant-looking skin this summer”. Rylan Clark: “I knew you was. I knew you was” … I have also heard Rylan Clark, British, 35 years old, say "the awfulest thing”

And in the same video clip at 10:09 he says "Welcome back, erm, we (unclear) looking at something this morning, wasn't we? Why are you remaining quiet? Because you loved this chat, we had this morning…”

If it wasn't clear, but I took it as a given, this is a nonstandard British dialect. Also,  I don't feel this speech is an offspring of AAVE, it is distinct and unique to itself.

@Mari-LouA I'm pretty sure Eliza Doolittle talked like this when Henry Higgens found her.
